# How to set a dynamic key name in a struct?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10, coldfusion-11

I am looping through a query and want to set the name of a struct key and its value dynamically. But I can't seem to get it to work because its not interpreting the dynamic value properly - it thinks its the actual name of the key. Here's what I mean

```
<cfloop query="rsSettings">
 <cfset APPLICATION.Config.Settings[rsSettings.CompanyID] = StructNew()>
 <cfset APPLICATION.Config.Settings[rsSettings.CompanyID].#rsSettings.Name#" = rsSettings.SettingValue/>
</cfloop>
```

I need the `#rsSettings.Name#` part to be the name value stored in that recordset e.g. "MaxOrders"

I tried putting quotes around it like this  `<cfset APPLICATION.Config.Settings[rsSettings.CompanyID]."rsSettings.Name" = rsSettings.SettingValue/>` but it doesn't work.

What can I do to make it accept a dynamic key name?

Comment: `[rsSettings.CompanyID]` is doing what you want, so chain them `[rsSettings.CompanyID].[rsSettings.Name]`

Comment: So how would I set the value of `[rsSettings.CompanyID].[rsSettings.Name]` ? I thought this creates another dimension to the struct

Comment: `<cfset APPLICATION.Config.Settings[rsSettings.CompanyID][rsSettings.Name]" = rsSettings.SettingValue/>` structs dont have dimensions, they have depth (i suppose) (and there is a typo in my first comment, the . between the two keys shouldn't be there

Comment: The StructInsert function is a very simply way to do exactly what you say you want to do.

Comment: You are already setting a dynamic key with `APPLICATION.Config.Settings[rsSettings.CompanyID]`. Why would you not follow that same syntax?

Comment: If this is inside the CFC we discussed yesterday, put "Config" in the CFC's variables scope and put the CFC itself into the application scope.

Comment: Also, you reaaallllly don't wan't to structNew() for each for of your query...otherwise you'll reset the structure on each row.

Comment: @JoeRinehart Thanks for the tip. What I did was create a Settings.cfc which I instantiated in Application.cfc.  Settings.cfc which has functions to do CRUD on company settings. So this first function is getting all the settings for every CompanyID. I don't understand what putting Config in the cfc's variables scope means - could you please let me know more? I thought I had to create a StructNew() for each CompanyID to hold all their settings... whats the alternative?

Comment: Yeah, you'll want to create a structure, but you'll only want to do it ONCE for each company ID. As written, you'll be wiping out all prior company settings on each iteration of their loop.

Reading this and some of your prior posts, you'd probably be well-served to get on board with a framework (I'd recommend FW/1) that'll handle a lot of these scoping and other issues you're encountering.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To make dynamic keys in a structure, you need to follow square `[]` braces notation. You can do it as follows:

```
<cfloop query="rsSettings">
     <cfset APPLICATION.Config.Settings[rsSettings.CompanyID] = StructNew()>
     <cfset APPLICATION.Config.Settings[rsSettings.CompanyID][rsSettings.Name] = rsSettings.SettingValue/>
</cfloop>
```

If you have multiple settings for a company (as mentioned by Joe) that you are getting from `rsSettings` query, then in that case you may need to check if the companyID already exists in `APPLICATION.Config.Settings`. Like this:

```
    <cfloop query="rsSettings">
         <cfif NOT structKeyExists(APPLICATION.Config.Settings, rsSettings.CompanyID) >
              <cfset APPLICATION.Config.Settings[rsSettings.CompanyID] = StructNew()>
         </cfif>
         <cfset APPLICATION.Config.Settings[rsSettings.CompanyID][rsSettings.Name] = rsSettings.SettingValue/>
    </cfloop>
```

Comment: As Joe pointed out, for each element in the `rsSettings` query, you will be creating a new structure, effectively overwriting the values from the last iteration.

Comment: Hey @ScottStroz, thanks me for pointing it out. I have updated my answer to solve the issue.

Comment: The problem now is how will settings won't get updated in application scope when they change.

Comment: @ScottStroz Whenever a company admin performs an update on their preferences, I'll fire off a RefreshSettings() function which will only update the Application scope variables for their CompanyID.